# using jquery to add portion of form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php form called st_record_rcs.php. It has a drop down menu that calls showFirstDiv(str):

```
function showFirstDiv(str) {
$('#div1').load('st_infopage.php?info_div1='+str); 
}



$query11 = "SELECT name, contact, street, city, state, zip, country, phone, email,ID FROM st_profiles WHERE type='S' ORDER BY `st_profiles` . `name` ASC "
or logfile($comment1,$random,$location,$access,$first,$is_address,$is_vendor,$is_inventory,$is_admin);

$result4 = $mysqli->query($query11);
$count1 = '0';
$column_count = mysqli_field_count($mysqli);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
for ($column_num = 0; $column_num < $column_count; $column_num++)
switch($column_num) {
case $column_num:
break;
} // END FOR LOOP

if ($count1 == '0') {
print ("<select name='shipper_addresses' onchange=\"showFirstDiv(this.value); \"  size='1' style='width:150; height:19; font-size:12px;' TABINDEX='1'>
<option value=''></option><option value='ADD'>[ADD NEW]</option>"); 

} 
print ("<option value='$row2[9]'>$row2[0]</option>");
$count1 = $count1 + 1;
} // END WHILE LOOP


print ("</select></td></tr>");

print ("<tr><td colspan='2'><div id='div1'><p> </p> </div></td></tr>");
```

This is FILE st_infopage.php

```
if ($_GET[info_div1]) {

if ($_GET[info_div1] != 'ADD') {    
$query11 = "SELECT street,ID FROM st_profiles WHERE ID='$_GET[info_div1]' ORDER BY `st_profiles` . `name` ASC "
or logfile($comment1,$random,$location,$access,$first,$is_address,$is_vendor,$is_inventory,$is_admin);

$result_name_check4  = $mysqli->query($query11);
$passcheck2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_name_check4, MYSQLI_NUM);    /* numeric array - meaning $passcheck[0] instead of $passcheck[user_id]*/

$shipper_street = $passcheck2[0]; 
} else {
$shipper_street = ''; 
}
echo "<table><input type='hidden' name='shipper_id' value='$shipper_id'>
<tr><td width='105' bgcolor='$shipstreet_color'>Shipper Name:</td><td><input type=text name='shipper_street' size=40 maxlength=40 style='width:150; height:18; font-size:10px;' value='$shipper_street' TABINDEX='2'></td></tr>
</table>";
    }
```

Everything works fine when I select the value from the drop-down it calls st_infopage.php the shipper information gets displayed in my form properly within the  tag.  Problem is when I submit the form from st_record_rcs.php the values within the  tag do not POST.  I'm not doing anything with the submit procedure.

```
<form name='theForm' action='st_record_rcs.php' method=post >.
```

All the other form values pass except for what's in the div tag.  How do I fix this?

Comment: **"Problem is when I submit the form from st_record_rcs.php"**, perhaps sharing the **submit** procedure would further help to finding a solution.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the submit procedure. <form name='theForm' action='st_record_rcs.php' method=post >. All the other form values pass except for what's in the <div> tag

Comment: Look at your generated HTML. Does the `<div>` sit inside the `<form>` that you are submitting? It is difficult for us to help you, unless you narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, from:

```
<form name='theForm' action='st_record_rcs.php' method=post >
```

I noticed that the form has **`method="POST"`** and **`action="st_record_rcs.php"`** attributes; but there isn't a corresponding **`$_POST["something"]`** in **`st_record_rcs.php`** to handle the fired HTTP request. So, below is my suggestion to the problem's solution, hope it will lead you down the right path.

Our `<form>` assumption:

```
<form name='theForm' action='st_record_rcs.php' method='POST'>
     <input type="text" name="userID">
     <button type="submit" name="submitRecordButton">Submit Record</button>
</form>
```

Our **`st_record_rcs.php`** would then have:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitRecordButton"])) {
     $userID = $_POST["userID"];
     // Do amazing things... or 

     /* for debugging's sake */
     echo $userID;
     exit;
}
```